# In Angular JS how to disable column sort feature for selected columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

In jquery data table I can disable specific column sort by

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [0, 7]
            }]
```

Anyone know how to do this in angular JS?

```
<table class="custom-table" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" id="contacts-list-table">
</table>

myApp.controller("ListCtr", ['DTOptionsBuilder', function(DTOptionsBuilder) {
  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withDOM('C<"clear">lfrtip') 
}])
```

this code hiding my search bar but not able to hide sort feature of my first and fourth column?

Comment: You want your tr elements to be not clickable? Can you post the tr code as well? It would be helpful if you paste the full table code.

Comment: One of the ways is you can use ng-click = "$event.stopPropogation();" for that div/tr element and manipulate it in js.... would give you a more specific answer if you give more details on how you implemented the table

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunker or post your code for table

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The angular-datatables equivalence to

```js
aoColumnDefs: [{ bSortable: false, aTargets: [0, 4] }]
```

is

```js
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
   DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable(),
   DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4).notSortable()
];
```

...

```html
<table class="custom-table" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" id="contacts-list-table"></table>
```

You must include `DTColumnDefBuilder` in the controller :

```js
myApp.controller("ListCtr", ['DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder',
    function(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
       $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withDOM('C<"clear">lfrtip');
       $scope.dtColumnDefs = [
          DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable(),
          DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4).notSortable()
       ];
    }
])
```

see **http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/api**.

Comment: do you know how to set "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1],[5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]] in angular data table

Comment: @vinothini, great you got it to work (apparently?) - regarding `aLengthMenu` there is no "translated" name / method, but then you should use `.withOption('aLengthMenu', [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1],[5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]])` in your case `$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withDOM('C<"clear">lfrtip').withOption('aLengthMenu', [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1],[5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]]);` ....`withOption()` simply add `this[key] = value` to the options literal.

Comment: @davidkonrad i am exacty suffering with the same issue.can you provide any help ?here is the link to my question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501820/disabling-angularjs-datatable-sorting-for-specified-columns

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every possible solution to disable sorting but the only thing that worked for me was : `order: false` . [Use this for reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order)

My `dtOptions` were as below

```
vm.dtOptions = {
        dom: '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"<"left"<"length"l>><"right"<"info"i><"pagination"p>>>',
        pagingType: 'simple',
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        order: false, // This fixed the issue
        columnDefs : [{
            targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], // column or columns numbers
            orderable: false,  // This was not working
            filterable: false,
            sortable  : false                
            },
            {
                // Target the actions column
                targets           : 8,
                responsivePriority: 1,
                filterable        : false,
                sortable          : false,
                orderable: false
            }                
        ]
    }
```