# How to disable initial Ordering of data in Angular Datatables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatables and I have only one column.

When I bind it, the data comes in an ascneding order, while I want to display it in the order I recived it.

Can someone please help.

Controller :

```
        var vm = this;
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withButtons([
            'print',
            'pdfHtml5',

        ]);
        vm.dtColumnDefs = [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()
        ];
```

HTML :

```
  <div ng-controller="formViewController as frmView">
    <table datatable="ng" dt-options="frmView.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="frmView.dtColumnDefs" class="row-border hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{Title}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="plugin in newArray track by $index">
                <td>
                    //Content
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027497/in-angular-js-how-to-disable-column-sort-feature-for-selected-columns

Comment: I already have what they say, I want to disable ordering, i.e. ascending-descending

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at [**`order`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order), formerly known as `aaSorting`. Add

```
.withOption('order', [])
```

to your `dtOptions`. The default value of order is `[[0, 'asc']]`, setting it to `[]` will prevent dataTables from making an initial sort on the first column after initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

> Resolved

```
this.dtOptions ={
 ajax:{},
 columns:[],
 order:[] //<= Use this
}
```

> This worked for me. I tried several other ways, but thus seems to be the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit() {
    // table settings
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      retrieve: true,
      order:[[0, 'desc']]   // '0' is the table column(1st column) and 'desc' is the sorting order
    }
  }
```