# disabling angularjs datatable sorting for specified columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sorting

I am working with angularjs data table where I don't need sorting for all the  columns. So I want to disable sorting for specified columns. I want to disable sorting for column no. 2 and 4 for the below case.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['datatables']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnBuilder) {

    $scope.list = [
        {"eid":"10","ename":"nam1","sales":"20"},
        {"eid":"20","ename":"nam2","sales":"20"},
        {"eid":"30","ename":"nam3","sales":"20"},
        {"eid":"40","ename":"nam4","sales":"20"}
    ];
    $scope.vm = {};

$scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withOption('order', [0, 'asc']);
$scope.vm.dtColumnDefs = [
   DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable(),
   DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3).notSortable()
];

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/datatables.bootstrap.css"> 
</head>
<div class="container">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="vm.dtColumnDefs" datatable="ng">
    <thead>
      <tr>
  <th>Employee ID</th>
 <th>name</th>
 <th>sales</th>
 <th>details</th>

</thead>
    <tbody>
  
   <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
      <td> {{ data.eid }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.ename }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.sales }} </td>
      <td>view</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I got the same issue and here is the what I have found; In my case I wanted to remove sorting feature from first column since it just contain a check box.

According to the official documentation this is the code block;

```
app.controller('exceptionViewCtrl', ['$scope', 'DTColumnDefBuilder',  function ($scope, $routeParams, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
    $scope.dtColumnDefs = [DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()];
}]);
```

But this is not worked; Then I figure out even if I disable sorting for a column, the dataTables sort `order` still remain. By default order is `[0, 'asc']`. So you need to additionally set `order` to target some other column instead.

So the complete html+angular code as follows;

**HTML**

```
<table datatable="" id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs">
     // table data
</table>
```

**Angular**

```
app.controller('exceptionViewCtrl', ['$scope', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', 'DTOptionsBuilder', function ($scope, DTColumnDefBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder) {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('order', [1, 'asc']);
    $scope.dtColumnDefs = [DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()];
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
    $scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
          .withOption('order', [0, 'asc']);
    $scope.vm.dtColumnDefs = [
       DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable(),
       DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3).notSortable()
    ];
});
```

Comment: i have edited my question with your answer but now i am getting DTColumnDefBuilder is not defined error!so it will be very much helpful if your can provide a code snippet  with your answer.

Comment: still getting Error: DTColumnDefBuilder is not defined

Comment: update your alias name defined in the controller section from DTColumnBuilder to DTColumnDefBuilder.